# The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from the computer

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I am trying to connect php in apache(xampp v5.6.8) to ms sql server 2012..it keeps giving me the error

> 'The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from the
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem'.

l downloaded and installed the visual c++ re-distributable for visual studio and located the MSVCP110.dll in my xampp php folder. It still gives the same error. Please can someone help.

Comment: Non-PHP DLLs should not reside in PHP directory. They belong in either program's or system's directory. Make sure you installed the right version of _Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4_, be it __32bit__ or __64bit__ . You can try copying that DLL to either _System32_ or _SysWoW64_ (depends on your system version) directory of windows __on your own risk__ .

Comment: Should l remove the msvcp110.dll in php directory in xampp.also l checked my system has a system32 and systemwow64 directory.in the system32 directory l found the msvcp110.dll file but it was not in the systemwow64. what should l do

Comment: When I finished typing _this_ comment I decided I'll rather post it combined with my first comment as an answer, please check it below.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that non-PHP DLLs should not reside in PHP directory. They belong in either program's or system's directory.

Make sure you installed the right version of *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4*, be it *32bit* or *64bit*. You can try copying that DLL to either *System32* or *SysWoW64* (depends on your system version) directory of windows **on your own risk**.

**UPDATE**:

From your comment I learned that your system is 64bit. The fact that you found that DLL in *System32* tells us that you installed 64bit Visual C++ Redistributables.

If your XAMPP is 32bit you should install **additionally** the same *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4* but **32bit** so your system has both of them, for 32bit and 64bit apps.

32bit applications don't use 64bit libraries. That should solve your problem.

Comment: you are correct on the fact that l have a 64bit system. following your previous statement l added the .dll file to the systemwow64 and it works but the php file outputs 'connection not established'

Comment: On a 64bit system: _System32_ has 64bit files and _SysWoW64_ has 32bit files. If you moved the file from one folder to another it's still the 64bit version. Read the second half of my answer again. Also, remove the file that you copied into SysWoW64, it may not be overwritten when you install 32bit VC++.

Comment: got you.am trying to download the 32bit vc++ now

Comment: connection could not be establishedArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5701 [code] => 5701 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'test'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'test'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code] => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_englis

Comment: thats the output l got. l download a new vc++ x86.for 32 bit systems and installed it from the download file.the output above is what l got.

Comment: `SQLSTATE 01000` means _Warning_. It looks like you don't have set default database and default language. That's what `5701` and `5703` tell us. Find out online how to do it for your SQL server type.

Comment: l selected the database l created and set the default database and default language.its still giving the same error

Comment: @user2546746 Glad I helped. If my answer helped you to solve your problem please see what to do next at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers